# DataTable merge treats duplicate PK as update rather than erroring

Tags: c#, system.data

I am trying to merge two `DataTable`s - one representing current data, and one representing proposed insertions to that data.

These tables have the same schema, both with a simple, user-provided primary key string.

What I'd *like* is, if the a proposed insertion row has a key that is already present in the current data, an error should be thrown. However, the proposed addition just gets merged as a proposed alteration to the existing row, which is *not* what I want.

My current code is something along the lines of

```
currentData.EnforceConstraints = false;
currentData.Merge(additions);
currentData.EnforceConstraints = true;
```

where I'm actually merging whole `DataSet`s, not just `DataTable`s. I was hoping to get an error on the `EnforceConstraints = true` line, but I don't.

I also tried using diffgrams, but had the same problem - duplicate insertions get treated as modifications.

Is there a way to merge a set of insertions into a `DataSet` and have duplicate PKs be treated as an *error* rather than an *update*?

---

Similarly, since *modified* `DataRow`s remember their original values, I'd hope that merging a modified row whose original values don't match the target row's current values would throw an exception too.

Comment: Did you check if your PK field is really as primary key field exposed to the datatable?

Comment: I just double-checked, and yes, it is the `PrimaryKey` for both the source and additions tables. (Maybe if I temporarily turned it off, it _wouldn't_ merge the values by key, then I could turn it back on and get an exception.)

Comment: "Make sure the key is a primary key and not just a key. It took me hours before I noticed that I'd forgotten to tick the "Primary key" checkbox in the data-table designer. Once I checked it my merge worked perfectly."

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the Unique flag used for this purpose? My understanding is that for Merge it will merge rows based on Primary Key.